# Drupal 8 :Uncaught PHP Exception UnexpectedValueException: "External URLs do not have an internal route name."

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have a custom themed site that has a menu structure like below
[Mega menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyD2c.png)

To achieve this I first created a menu called "MENU MAIN" with all the required links and then created another menu called "MEGA MENU" with one single link. Thereafter I used layout builder to create a layout for that particular link in "MEGA MENU" and by using layout builder blocks I added the menu items in different columns over there. Everything works perfectly fine now. But now when I try to add an external link to any of the menu items in "MENU A" like HTTP://example.com/abcd the entire site breaks. I checked the server error logs and found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chqDz.png)

Please get me a solution for this.